# MediaStream to RTMP in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

- read stream from webcam "MediaStream"
- ingest the mediaStream to RTMP server
- basically need an RTMP converter

or any other way to achieve the same broadcast video from webcam to youtube live.

any suggested JS libraries to achieve the second part of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have built a Node backend that takes the MediaStream from your webcam and converts it to RTMP with FFMPEG - which can then be ingested at Twitch or YouTube Live In my example, I am using [api.video](https://api.video) in the code to create live streams.
You can [try it out](http://livestream.streamclarity.com/), and the code is on [Github](https://github.com/dougsillars/browserLiveStream):

It is really lightweight (the demo is running on an AWS Micro instance).  In the demo, you can adjust the size (dimensions and framerate) of the video - but as you increase the dimensions, you are more likely to hit uplink issues if your network is slow or has high latency.

Comment: can you tell me the purpose of 
1) api.video
2) FFMPEG Node backend

so if my understanding is correct 
MediaStream(browser) => FFMPEG( Node) => api.video => RTMP Endpoint
is this correct ? then why not FFMPEG convert to RTMP format.

Comment: Video flow is as follows:
MediaStream(browser) -> FFMPEG (Node) this creates the FLV format for RTMP -> api.video (converts FLV/RTMP into HLS video stream to be watched live in browsers/mobile devices.). api.video has the scaling to handle the live streaming with a large numbers of viewers, and can also record/host the stream for replay as video on demand.